# Pandas: Find the highest probability of keywords in text column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have the following list of keywords. I want to find the highest probability of keywords in each rows of the column. Probability will be calculated like this:

```
Probability(keyword class) = total no. of keywords in the list / total no. of words in the row
```

Now generate a column `label` to return the keyword class having highest probability.

`fruits = [mango, apple, lichi]`
`animals = [dog, cat, cow, monkey]`
`country = [us, ca, au, br]`

Expected Output:

| content | label |
| --- | --- |
| My favorite fruit is mango. I like lichies too. I live in au. Cows are domistic animals. | fruits |
| I own RTX 4090... | NaN |
| There is political colfict between us and ca. | country |
| au, br mango, lichi apple,.... \n cat, cow, monkey donkey dogs | animals |

`content 1: P(fruits) = 2/17, P(animals) = 1/17, P(country)=1/17 Highest Probability: fruits`
`content 2: P(fruits) = 0, P(animals) = 0, P(country)=0 Highest Probability: NaN`
`content 3: P(fruits) = 0/8, P(animals) = 0/8, P(country)=2/8 Highest Probability: country`
`content 4: P(fruits) = 3/10, P(animals) = 4/10, P(country)=2/10 Highest Probability: animals`

N.B: If the probability is equal then retun any of the label. Avoid exact string matching. For example:   `I like lichies too`, here `lichi` keyword will be counted.

Code I tried:

```
def calculate_probability(row):
    words = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', row['content'].lower())
    word_count = len(words)
    
    fruit_prob = sum(word in fruits for word in words) / word_count if word_count > 0 else 0
    animal_prob = sum(word in animals for word in words) / word_count if word_count > 0 else 0
    country_prob = sum(word in country for word in words) / word_count if word_count > 0 else 0
    
    probabilities = {'fruits': fruit_prob, 'animals': animal_prob, 'country': country_prob}
    max_label = max(probabilities, key=probabilities.get)
    return max_label if probabilities[max_label] > 0 else 'NaN'


df['label'] = df['content'].apply(calculate_probability, axis=1)
```

Not getting expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You are applying your function on a Series, but your function takes a DataFrame a input. Rewrite the function to handle a Series. Also, remove `axis=1`.

Here is an updated (and improved) version of the function:

```
import re
from collections import Counter

labels = {'fruits': ['mango', 'apple', 'lichi'],
          'animals':  ['dog', 'cat', 'cow', 'monkey'],
          'country': ['us', 'ca', 'au', 'br'],
         }

def calculate_probability(text, labels):
    words = re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', text.lower())
    word_count = len(words)
    
    counts = Counter(words)

    probs = {k: sum(counts[w] for w in l)/word_count
             for k, l in labels.items()}
    
    max_label = max(probs, key=probs.get)
    return max_label if probs[max_label] > 0 else 'NaN'


df['label'] = df['content'].apply(calculate_probability, labels=labels)
```

Output:

```
                                             content    label
0  My favorite fruit is mango. I like lichies too...   fruits
1                                  I own RTX 4090...      NaN
2      There is political colfict between us and ca.  country
3  au, br mango, lichi apple,.... \n cat, cow, mo...   fruits
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explode your content as token the use a dict mapping to match each token to a class:

```
labels = {  # add some plural nouns
    'fruits': ['mango', 'apple', 'lichi', 'lichies'],
    'animals': ['dog', 'cat', 'cow', 'monkey', 'cows'],
    'country': ['us', 'ca', 'au', 'br'],
}
token2class = {v: k for k, l in labels.items() for v in l}

classes = df['content'].str.lower().str.split(r'[\s.,]+').explode().map(token2class).dropna().reset_index()
df['label'] = classes.pivot_table(index='index', columns='content', aggfunc='size').idxmax(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                             content    label
0  My favorite fruit is mango. I like lichies too...   fruits
1                                  I own RTX 4090...      NaN
2      There is political colfict between us and ca.  country
3  au, br mango, lichi apple,.... \n cat, cow, mo...  animals

>>> classes
    index  content
0       0   fruits
1       0   fruits
2       0  country
3       0  animals
4       2  country
5       2  country
6       3  country
7       3  country
8       3   fruits
9       3   fruits
10      3   fruits
11      3  animals
12      3  animals
13      3  animals
```

**Note**: Use something like `ntlk` to tokenize correctly sentences into words. Here the split is very basic. You can also lemmatize plural nouns, etc.

Comment: In the current example, the last text had an equal probability for animals/fruits, I agree a NL approach would be better.